# Verification of the definitions of joint and marginal distribution functions.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

I was studying measure theory and now I'm going to probability. I know the usual definitions of joint and marginal CDF's.  But I'm particularly interested to define these concepts looking the probability as a measure. To do so, I wrote the following.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and let $X,Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Define the **joint distribution function** as $F_{XY}(x,y)=P_{XY}((-\infty,x]\times (-\infty,y])=P\{X(w)\leq x,Y(w)\leq y\}$, where $P_{XY}: \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is the **joint probability distribution** (or the pushforward measure) of $X$ and $Y$. Given the joint distribution function $F_{XY}$, the **marginal distribution function** of $X$ is defined as $F_X(x)=P_{XY}\{(-\infty,x]\times\mathbb{R}\}$

I would like to read your comments on my definitions. Specially, if they are correctly defined.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost all is correct. One thing, I'd rather use $\mathbb F_{(X,Y)}$ rather than $F_{XY}$ and similarly with $P$, cause it can be misunderstood for distribution of rv $Z = XY$. However, it's just a notation and if you define so, then it should be fine. However, $ F_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : (X,Y)(\omega) \in (-\infty,x] \times (-\infty, y] \}) = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \le x, Y(\omega) \le y \})$. You shouldn't use different $\omega_1, \omega_2$ because the sample point ( $\omega$ ) need to be the same for both $X,Y$ simultaneously

Comment: You are completely right. Thank you for the comment!